# change UI dynamically according to location

Tags: applications

I want to know how in Uber app, type of cab availability options are changed dynamically according to user's location? e.g. 'airport to city' option in airport location.

Comment: See **[Location-based Services](https://www.google.com/search?q=location+based+services)**

Answer (score 0):

Create the usual splash screen as specified in the below tutorial then you can do a background process which checks on the location then change the imageView dynamically.[http://www.androidhive.info/2013/07/how-to-implement-android-splash-screen-2/]